# Facebook app - like and share links using social plugins inside FB app

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-apps, facebook-sharer, facebook-share

I'm developing a facebook app for a page .. the app has products and I want to add like and share for each product inside the app using facebook social plugins .. my problem is with the like and share link since facebook apps are actually webapps loaded in iframes.

for example for product with id 1, for example assume my url is: https://www.myapp.com/products/1 (the url set in the facebook app setting, currently I'm using ngrok to provide public https link cause I'm still in development mode).. the url is accessable in the browser but not through the facebook crawler (in the share debugger it returns response code 0) .. I've put the open graph meta tags in the product page but it seems the problem the crawler can't even reach my links.

So how can I put the links in the right way so that they are discoverable by the crawler and can be accessed whether the user accesses the app from the page tab or search for it .. and also when shared/liked on a user's feed, the link should redirect the user to the product page inside the facebook app?

Comment: there is no valid ssl certificate, that may be the problem. also, there are 2 blank lines before the doctype.

Comment: yes for now in development mode I'm using ngrok to generate an https link since I'm in development mode .. ngrok gives you https link with valid certificate

Comment: _“the url is accessable in the browser but not through the facebook crawler”_ - well then you need to fix your local setup ... we can’t do that for you. What have you done so far to debug this? Checked the log files for incoming requests from Facebook, and possible reasons why the get blocked/rejected/... from your ngrok?

Comment: ngrok doesn't receive a request in the logs .. maybe I'm doing it wrong .. what is the right way to add a url in share or like buttons inside a facebook app? should I put https://www.someexample.com/products/1 or should I put https://apps.facebook.com//{app_id} and then there is a way to redirect to the products page in my app?